# Delete <script> after function call

Tags: javascript

I have a php website that is generating heck ton of `<script> somefunction(...) </script>`
The issue is that I don't really enjoy website with all those elements.
Is there a way to delete  element after the function is called?

What I mean is that I would like it to do something like this:

```
<script>
   somefunction();
   delete_script_element();
</script>
```

and that delete_script_element() is able to get the  element it called in, and then removes it, I guess simply by:

```
function delete_script_element() {
   document."GetParentElement".remove();
}
```

I potentially can also put the code in each , but I still don't know how to target the parent  element.

Any help appreciated ^^

Comment: for a script to remove itself ... `document.currentScript.remove()`

Comment: @nimo - Just to be clear, though: deleting the element does not delete the functions, etc., that the code in the element created.

Comment: Yeah, I know, all I wanted to delete is the function call and the <script> element, but keep the functions that are in separate .js file.

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP tag since the question/issue is 100% about JS. And tbh, why does it really matter if there are some extra script tags in the source? Adding code to remove them after the functions been called will just add unnecessary complexity (and will most likely make it much harder to debug since the code you need to check might have been removed.) Always thrive for simplicity.

Comment: Basically I wrote myself a popup and roast-notifications system, and I know it most likely not professional, but php generating the code adds them as function calls with parameters, and i didnt like having a like row of 60 <script> elements, plus, some data was hidden by "devmode", basically If i assigned the notificaiton higher dev mode, it first check if the user has high enough dev mode, but its javascript sided, stored in localStorage, not cookies, and if the user doesnt have the devmode, it wont show, its not data that will get me hacked or release private information, just... looks ugly.

Comment: Also, code looks cleaner, and I like that x3